# EF 6 Migrations issue with multiple DBcontext

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I created a new ASP.NET MVC 5 project and ended up with 2 DBContext :

-ApplicationDBContext for Identity.

-myDBContext for my objects

For both i used the same connection string so both ASP Identity tables and business object tables are in the same Database.

But this creates such a mess:
When i do migration for one the DB context, the app complains that ApplicationDbContext has been modified.
When i do migration for ApplicationDbContext, the app complains that myDBContext has been modified..
I m lost here...
Can someone explain me what's happening there?
Thanks
Jonathan

Comment: Are there any tables that are common to both contexts?

Comment: As table in common for both context, it is a a good question. Even if now there are 2 tables in common, the error occured even before this situation